# It is impossible to divide any curved figure into a finite number of polygons?

Tags: geometry

By a curved figure, I mean any figure with a boundary that is not a straight line. If this statement is true, is it possible to give a simple proof?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint** What does the boundary of a polygon look like? What then does the boundary of any finite union of polygons look like?